# In C++, can I polymorphically handle data that may or may not have certain methods able to be called on it

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

First of all, sorry for the bad question title. I can't figure out a short way to describe my problem.

I'm currently trying to write a small library with file IO (for learning purposes).

My issue is that I've created a base class, `File`, that basically holds the buffer to read to or write from.

It looks a bit like this (some things that don't matter were removed):

```
class File {
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> contents; // The buffer for reading into/writing from.
    size_t pos; // The offset from the beginning of the buffer.
}
```

Of course, I need to add methods for reading and writing to the file/buffer. I want to make it possible to open a file as Read Only, Write Only, or Read-Write.

My problem arises when I want to make it so other objects can handle a file without caring if it is read-only, write-only, or read-write.

The logical way to do this is to make a `ReadFile` class, like this:

```
class ReadFile : public File {
    std::string getAll();
    std::string getLine();
    char getByte();
};
```

Note that this class only adds methods, not any additional data.

Similarly, I wrote a `WriteFile` class:

```
class WFile : public FileBase {
    void putString(const std::string&);
    void putByte(char);

    void save(const std::string& filename);
}
```

This class also only adds methods.

However, if I want to make the `ReadWriteFile` class, I have to inherit from both the `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` class. This, of course, creates the diamond problem, since both `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` inherit from the base `File`.

I've come up with a few solutions, but none have given me the exact thing I want.

The first is virtual inheritance. However, this seems to add unnecessary overhead and `vtable`s to the compiled code. I shouldn't need any sort of virtual functions, since I'm only adding methods to the class, not overriding them.

The second is removing the inheritance completely, and instead using templates and `enable_if` to conditionally allow methods to be called on a class, but this seems like overkill, as well as extremely hard to do.

Is there a simple way to polymorphically treat these files without any (run-time) overhead? After all, this can be figured out all during compile time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the standard `<iostream>` Input/Output library, you'll see that it uses virtual inheritance to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you plan to use your classes in the code that must deal with them polymorphically?